# What Is this Imputation Method Called?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na, imputation

I am imputing NAs with a randomly selected value from the data. The randomly selected values are weighted according to their frequency. For example I have 5 values:

```
[1,1,2,3,NA]
```

There is a 50% chance I would replace it with a 1, and a 25% chance for 2, and 25% chance for 3. Does that make sense?

I wrote the following function to do this across a larger dataset and am using it in a report, and I would like to properly refer to this imputation method because I am guessing that it already exists and is named.

```
my.imputer <- function(x) {
x[which(is.na(x))] <- sample(na.omit(x),
                             length(x[which(is.na(x))]),
                             replace = TRUE,
                             prob = sort(sapply(na.omit(x),
                       function(y) table(y) / length(na.omit(x)))))
}
```

Comment: If you are asking for names of imputation methods, then you are better off asking the statisticians over at [stats.se]. There's no real programming question here.

Comment: Likelihood-based imputation

Comment: Thank you @akash87.  MrFlick I will post stuff like this on Cross Validated from now on. Thanks!

Comment: There is no in general agreed term for your specific method. It usually is referred as Random Imputation, Simplistic Imputation or like askash87 suggested Likelihood-based imputation. With these terms rather describing a group of algorithms than a specific one. I would state in your report that you are using Likelihood-based imputation that replaces missing data according to ... shouln't anyway need more than two sentences to describe your method.